# Is there an option in ace editor to avoid horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

In ace editor if the text is too long, a horizontal scroll bar is appearing, is there an option in ace editor, if text is too long it automatically breaks in multiple lines.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, use `wrap: true` option.

```html
<script src=https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js></script>
<div id=editor style="height:90vh"></div>
<script>
editor = ace.edit("editor", {
  wrap: true, 
  value: "very long line ".repeat(120)
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `wrap: 1` in the options

```
editor = ace.edit("editor", {
  wrap: 1
})
```